# How to draw a cutaway diagram of concentric balls?

Tags: graphics3d, image3d

**Background**
The [help index](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SphericalPlot3D.html) shows how to draw 3D cutaways of concentric spheres:

```
SphericalPlot3D[{1, 2, 3}, {\[Theta], 0, Pi}, {\[Phi], 0, 3 Pi/2}]
```

[image]

The [Ball command](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ball.html?q=Ball) creates 3D balls.

**Question**
How can we draw a cutaway diagram of concentric balls? Could the shell thicknesses in the figure above be increased to fill the gaps?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since `RegionPlot3D` not so smooth and `CSGRegion` does not support `Show`,here we use another way.

- Use `SliceContourPlot3D` and `"CenterCutSphere"`.

```
SliceContourPlot3D[
 x^2 + y^2 + z^2, "CenterCutSphere", {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 
  3}, Contours -> {1^2, 2^2}, Boxed -> False, 
 ContourShading -> {Red, Green, Blue}]
```

[image]

- Use `"OpenCascadeLink`"`.

```
Needs["OpenCascadeLink`"];
b3 = Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 3];
b2 = Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 2];
b1 = Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 1];
c = Cuboid[{0, 0, -3}, {3, 3, 3}];
(*c=Cuboid[{0,0,0},{3,3,3}];*)

shape3 = OpenCascadeShape[b3];
shape2 = OpenCascadeShape[b2];
shape1 = OpenCascadeShape[b1];
shape = OpenCascadeShape[c];
difference32 = 
  OpenCascadeShapeDifference[
   OpenCascadeShapeDifference[shape3, shape2], shape];
difference21 = 
  OpenCascadeShapeDifference[
   OpenCascadeShapeDifference[shape2, shape1], shape];
difference10 = OpenCascadeShapeDifference[shape1, shape];
bmesh32 = 
  OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[difference32, 
   "ShapeSurfaceMeshOptions" -> {"AngularDeflection" -> .1}];
bmesh21 = 
  OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[difference21, 
   "ShapeSurfaceMeshOptions" -> {"AngularDeflection" -> .1}];
bmesh10 = 
  OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[difference10, 
   "ShapeSurfaceMeshOptions" -> {"AngularDeflection" -> .1}];
Show[bmesh32[
  "Wireframe"[
   "MeshElementStyle" -> 
    Directive[EdgeForm[], FaceForm[Darker@Cyan]]]], 
 bmesh21["Wireframe"[
   "MeshElementStyle" -> Directive[EdgeForm[], FaceForm[Yellow]]]], 
 bmesh10["Wireframe"[
   "MeshElementStyle" -> Directive[EdgeForm[], FaceForm[Red]]]], 
 ViewPoint -> {1, 1, 1}, ViewProjection -> "Orthographic", 
 Boxed -> False]
```

[image]